# Proof involving complex limits

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty } \left | z_{n} - z \right | = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty } Re(z_{n}) = Re(z)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty } Im(z_{n}) = Im(z)$.

I understand the epsilon delta definition for limits of complex functions, but I'm getting confused since there is no clear function of z.

Comment: The function of $z$ is $f(z) = z$.

Comment: $z$ is not a function here, it is simply a complex number.  Likewise, the sequence $z_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers, not complex functions.

Comment: In order to start the proof in the positive direction would a good approach be to use the epsilon delta definition for the first limit?

Comment: You want the test "$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n=s$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$ there's an $N$ such that $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$."  I.e., not epsilon delta but epsilon $N$, to coin a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can apply following inequalities:
\begin{align}
|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)-\operatorname{Re}(z)|&\le |z_n - z|\\
|\operatorname{Im}(z_n)-\operatorname{Im}(z)|&\le |z_n - z|\\
|z_n-z|&\le |\operatorname{Re}(z_n)-\operatorname{Re}(z)|+|\operatorname{Im}(z_n)-\operatorname{Im}(z)|.
\end{align}